# Prevent formula input in all cells in a column, but allow whole number input

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I am in a bit of a sticky situation. There is a public spreadsheet that some of my coworkers are required to use for their job. They all collectively use it during their shifts to track product information. There is an issue between some older coworkers who have been using a calculator to input whole numbers into a spreadsheet for years, and a younger employee, who likes to input formulas to do the math for him.

I personally agree with his method of utilizing the excel spreadsheet, but its hard to teach an old dog new tricks, and the younger employee refuses to just leave the spreadsheet alone. Problem is, when he gets off shift and forgets to change his formulas back, the rest of the older guys get frustrated.

They came to me to request that I lock him out of being able to insert formulas in this particular column. The problem is, I can't simply protect the spreadsheet as there are 5-6 users needing access to it 24/7. I'm also attempting to make the process simpler for the older employees, not more complicated. Is there a way that I can simply deny formula entry in the cells of one particular column without requiring a password or locking out all data-entry altogether?

Comment: I think the real answer lies in talking with your younger employee or older employees. Simply adding a formula lock on cells doesn't solve the underlying problem of why you're having to put one in the first place. It's a band-aid that will likely disgruntle one or both parties. Someone has to give.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach that should satisfy both sides would be to add a before_save macro that simply copies/pastes-values the column before saving.

Anyone who enters formulae will be happy because they can still do so. The old fogies who can't cope with modern IT will be happy because they wont have to get their hands dirty with formulae.

---

Better still, change the spreadsheet into a simple web app and annoy everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for column **D**; you can adapt it to any column.  This *Event* macro monitors changes made to column **D**.  If a user attempts to enter a formula in column **D**, the entry is reversed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim D As Range, ints As Range
    Set D = Range("D:D")
    Set ints = Intersect(D, Target)
    If ints Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If ints.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If ints.HasFormula Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The only restriction is to allow only one cell at a time to be changed.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**